# Find the command and options used by NetBeans IDE

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I am using a the NetBeans 7.x IDE.   I have a Netbeans Application module.  I use the Build and the Run buttons from the IDE. The module runs just fine when I press Run Project or F6 button.  I like to run
this from the command line.  Since everything was build automatically for
me I have no idea where things are or how to run it.  There are several jar files in the project/build/public-package-jars.  Is there a way  to see what command and options the Run Project is using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the root of the application (or wherever there is a `build.xml` file) on the command line and run `ant -p`.  That will list all of the available options for building and running the application.